# Return the subclass in the abstract class in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have simplified my problem to the following situation:

```js
abstract class Foo {
  child: Foo
  foo(): Foo {
    return this.child
  }
}
class Bar extends Foo {
  bar = true
}
const foo = new Bar()
// Property 'bar' does not exist on type 'Foo'. ts(2339)
foo.foo().bar
```

This error is self explanatory and unsurprising, but what I want to achieve is that `foo()` returns something of the subclass type. In this case that would be `Bar`, such that I can use its property `bar`. We could achieve this like so:

```js
abstract class Foo<C extends Foo<C>> {
  child: C
  foo(): C {
    return this.child
  }
}
class Bar extends Foo<Bar> {
  bar = true
}
const foo = new Bar()
foo.foo().bar
```

Yay, the error is solved! However I also want to use `this` inside `Foo` the same way I use `C`, i.e. the subclass type:

```js
abstract class Foo<C extends Foo<C>> {
  foo(): C {
    // Type 'this' is not assignable to type 'C'.
    // 'this' is assignable to the constraint of type 'C',
    // but 'C' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'Foo<C>'. ts(2322)
    return this
  }
}
class Bar extends Foo<Bar> {
  bar = true
}
const foo = new Bar()
foo.foo().bar
```

We can't though, as TypeScript isn't aware that the subclass type passed as a type parameter is actually the same as the actual subclass type.

**Is there a way to approach this different such that I won't have this error?**

I could workaround it by casting `this` like so: `this as unknown as C`, letting TypeScript know to trust us that it actually is the same, but as I have plenty of code using `this` in a context where `C` is expected, this is something I rather not do.

**Edit**: Rather than having a base class I started out using a few functions that contained the shared functionality:

```js
interface Foo {
  child: Foo
}
function fooFn<C extends Foo>(parent: C, child: C): C {
  return child
}
class Bar implements Foo {
  child: Bar
  bar = true
  foo() {
    return fooFn(this, this.child)
  }
}
const foo = new Bar()
foo.foo().bar
```

This worked well for my use case, but now that it became like 20 such functions, I felt the boilerplate of having those methods directly calling the functions could be replaced by a base class, but then I ran into this issue.

Answer (score 3):

I looked more into this pattern as I saw some vague mentions of it being used too in C++ and C# and apparently it is called the [Curiously Recurring Template Pattern (CRTP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern). And they just cast `this` too in their examples, so seems like the legit way to go about it. As I am more familiar with C#, I looked for an example of it instead and found [a post](https://zpbappi.com/curiously-recurring-template-pattern-in-csharp/) with this example:

```cs
public abstract class AlgorithmBase<TDerived>
    where TDerived : AlgorithmBase<TDerived>
{
    public TDerived Run()
    {
        this.Step1();
        this.Step2();
        // ...
        this.StepN();
        this.FinalStep();
        
        return (TDerived)this;
    }
    
    protected abstract void Step1();
    protected abstract void Step2();
    // ...
    protected abstract void StepN();
    protected abstract void FinalStep();
}
```

Which translated to TypeScript would become:

```
abstract class AlgorithmBase<TDerived extends AlgorithmBase<TDerived>> {
  run(): TDerived {
    this.step1();
    this.step2();
    // ...
    this.stepN();
    this.finalStep();
    
    return this as any; // or: as unknown as TDerived,
    // but that is unnecessary as we already gave an explicit return type
  }

  protected abstract step1();
  protected abstract step2();
  // ...
  protected abstract stepN();
  protected abstract finalStep();
}
```

If there were better ways of going about this, I would have expected them to have wikipedia pages and posts about them instead, so I think this is as good as it gets.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for sharing. It's always nice to see when you get it right. XD

Answer (score 2):

You are fighting against the type checking of typescript.

There is always the hacky way around it. The any type **can** be used to return C:

```js
return this as any
```

Typescript is doing what is expected, and protects you from yourself.
Forcing an object into an extended class leads to data loss, so you need to show the compiler you know this.

Comment: So you are saying that I have the right approach for what I am trying to achieve and this situation is a fair case of having to cast to any, as this is not really well expressed in TypeScript any other way?

Comment: I ran into similar situations before where I didn't have any choice, I **feel like** this is one too. You can probably get around this in some other way (I honestly don't know, but there usually always is). I think the question is: "Is it worth the amount of code needed to do this in that other way, or would it just clutter and diminish readability?" If your code does what it is supposed to, I'd go for this. But I am by no means an expert in typescript, I just have been in similar situations.

Comment: I doubt there are really much better ways, given this is a recurring pattern in multiple languages (see my answer), but you are right, it is probably good enough, as other solutions might result in more boilerplate.

Comment: Hello, it's actually much simpler than you thought. Check my answer. Without `polymorphic this type`, it would be hard to design builders properly in TS.

Answer (score 1):

In typescript, you can type the return of a method as `this`. Typing so will magically use the type of the subclass, not the extended one.

Here is your example rewritten:

```js
abstract class Foo {
  foo(): this {
    return this
  }
}

class Bar extends Foo {
  bar = true
}

const foo = new Bar()
foo.foo().bar
```

As simple as `this`

The [official documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#polymorphic-this-types) calls this "polymorphic this type"